# 95% CI in nonlinear mixed-effect model {lme4} with two or more crossed random effects

Tags: confidence-interval, random-effects-model, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nonlinear

I have fisheries-independent data and am interesting in estimating maturity patterns across 50 lakes that are sampled (with bias) by 4 types of gear-collections. The sampling pattern is very unbalanced, some lakes are data-rich and some lakes are data-poor. Additionally, some lakes are sampled by 2 or 3 of the gears, some lakes are sampled by only 1 gear. Some lakes have only had mature fish sampled, some lakes have only had immature fish sampled.

So there are some sampling issues that I chose to tackle with using a nonlinear mixed-effects model, where the random effects are an age-at-50% probability of maturity that varies by lake and by gear. Importantly, I am choosing that the random effects are crossed, and not nested, as I suspect that a gear (e.g., a gillnet survey) is going to have similar bias on sampling the age/maturity structure in Lake A, as it does in Lake B. In this way, the gears are deployed and used in a "standardized" manner across lakes. Hence, I believe they are crossed random effects.

Quickly, my question lies in: how best to bracket uncertainty via 95% Confidence Intervals in a parameter that has two or more crossed random effects (i.e., the a50 parameters per lake per gear combination)?

Details below:

I have chosen a maturity curve with a sigmoidal logistic regression:

```
P(maturity) = 1/(1+exp(-log(19)*((age-a50)/delta)))
```

or

$$
P(\textrm{maturity}) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\log(19)(\textrm{age}-a_{50})/\delta)}
$$

Here the log(19) constrains the delta parameter to estimate the difference (in the units of age; which is years) in age at 50% probability of maturity and the age at 95% probability. The nice part of this is that it reduces correlation between an a50 parameter and an a95 parameter (in a previous model, this correlation was around 0.40 or higher) and instead estimates a50 and delta with ~0.04 correlation. My preliminary analyses indicate that the delta parameter does not vary, and thus the maturity curves by lake by gear combination are parallel and vary only in the age at 50% maturity.

I assume that the a50 for lake i and gear j is:

```
a50{i,j} = a50{global/fixed} + 
            {random effect per lake i} + 
            {random effect per gear j}
```

*and therefore the 95% CI can be calculated based on the Standard Error of the Random Effects:*

```
95% CI of [a50{i,j}] = 
a50{global/fixed} +  
({random effect per lake i} +/- 1.96*{Std. Err. random effect per lake i}) + 
({random effect per gear j} +/- 1.96*{Std. Err. random effect per gear j})
```

*Or alternatively the 95% CI could be all based on Standard Errors on the fixed effects:*

```
95% CI of [a50{i,j}] = 
a50{global/fixed} +/- 1.96{Std. Error a50[global/fixed]} + 
{random effect lake i} + 
{random effect gear j}
```

Or there are some other solutions to this issue with which I am unfamiliar. I am using the `arm` package and the `lme4` package in R. I am mostly confused whether the Std. Errors for the crossed random effects are simply additive (i.e., it is 1.96*Std_Err of Lake effect + 1.96*Std_Err of Gear Effect) or whether it should be calculated differently.

My issue isn't coding or syntax though. I am just confused but very interested in describing the uncertainty around the estimated a50 coefficients per lake per gear type.

For the purposes of using {lme4} I follow the steps below:

```
maturity_model <- function(age,a50,delta)
{
  1/(1+exp(-log(19)*((age-a50)/delta)))
}

maturity_Gradient <- deriv(body(maturity_model)[[2]],
                           namevec=c("a50","delta"),
                           function.arg=maturity_model)

contr <- nlmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e6))
maturity_fit <- nlmer(
  # Response
  mat ~ 
    # Fixed effects
    maturity_Gradient(age=OT1,a50,delta) ~ 
    # Random effects
    (a50|Waterbody.ID) + (a50|Gear_typ), 
  # Data
  data = matu, 
  start = c(a50=15,delta=12),nAGQ=1,control=contr)

library(arm)
se_matu <- se.ranef(maturity)
se_fixed <- se.fixef(maturity)
```

Once I get the SE's by random effects or fixed effects I can do lots of things here that will be useful, but just don't quite know what the best approach is when there are "three levels of standard errors": the SE in the fixed effects, the SE in the random lake effect, and the SE in the random gear effect.

Comment: Just to maybe guide some thoughts: I know that standard error on the coefficients could be estimated in ADMB-RE, and we could use Gelman et al. '{arm}' package to estimate the posterior distributions of the coefficients. Just looking for some insight on what the 95% CI on coefficients look like when there are two crossed random effects. Is what I've listed above seem reasonable for calculations?